# Ordering splitted categories by date

Tags: r, split

Assume following dataset named df:

```
Product Quantity Date

X       1        15/3/2015
Y       2        16/4/2014
X       1        21/5/2015 
X       2        11/12/2014
 Z      1        2/10/2015 
Y       1        17/5/2014 
Z       2        18/5/2014
Z       1        6/5/2015
Y       2        9/6/2014
```

I want to split the dataframe based on the different product categories and then order each of the categories by date.I used following code to split my dataset

```
df2 <- split(df, df$Date)
```

I tried df3 <- df2[order(df2$Date),] but this gaves me the error that argument 1 is not a vector (makes sense).

Is there a way to order each of the splitted categories by date? And in general, does the split function allow me to perform functions on each of the splitted categories? Note that my real dataset is one that contains over 1000 product categories.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with `dplyr` if you don't need the Products to remained split.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), "%d/%m/%Y")

library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Product) %>%
    arrange(Date)


Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: Product

  Product Quantity       Date
1       X        2 2014-12-11
2       X        1 2015-03-15
3       X        1 2015-05-21
4       Y        2 2014-04-16
5       Y        1 2014-05-17
6       Y        2 2014-06-09
7       Z        2 2014-05-18
8       Z        1 2015-05-06
9       Z        1 2015-10-02
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution. I used `lubridate` to convert the `Date` column to Date but this step is not required if your data are already a data format.
Your code does not work because `split` returns a list; in order to make a code that has sense and works properly you have to loop trough the list and order each column `Date` of each element of the list (which is a data frame of the `Product`).

```
library(lubridate)
df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)

dfs <- split(df, df$Product)
lapply(dfs, function(x) x[order(x$Date), ] )
$X
Product Quantity       Date
4       X        2 2014-12-11
1       X        1 2015-03-15
3       X        1 2015-05-21

$Y
Product Quantity       Date
2       Y        2 2014-04-16
6       Y        1 2014-05-17
9       Y        2 2014-06-09

$Z
Product Quantity       Date
7       Z        2 2014-05-18
8       Z        1 2015-05-06
5       Z        1 2015-10-02
```